# Get Number.toLocaleString passing an ISO 3166 Alpha 2 code

Tags: javascript, locale, number-formatting

I need to get a country's number representation by passing it the country's Alpha 2 code (for example GB, IT, VN) in JavaScript.

From what I've seen in the docs you can only pass it the ISO 639-1 code? (for example en_US). If it's not possible to pass it the 3166 code directly then I would need a way to convert such code into the language code.

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it? There's a fallback mechanism for the string supplied. e.g. `1234567.89.toLocaleString()` with "us" and "uk" yields different and correct results.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a difference between 3166 and 639-1 for some countries (Vietnam has VN for 3166 and vi for 639-1). A Java implementation would also be ok if it solves the problem, but I have already tried using DecimalFormat and for some countries it doesn't work (does not return space thousand separator) or it differs with the result returned from JS` Number.toLocaleString.